# "stringy" polarized water effect

Tags: after-effects

**Scenario**

I saw this on a vimeo video and I want to try and recreate it. I've been using the various particle systems in after effects CC but I can't figure out how to get the particles to be "sticky" to one-another.

**Question**

How can I create a stringy / ropey water dribble effect similar to the clip below?

https://cl.ly/a576fc863a00

Comment: Tried Blender? Might have some more success in there.

Comment: @mark great suggestion! I found someone who made the kind of "gooeyness" I'm looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG7kBkGLJ30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Mark's comment I used blender to do this. I followed this [tutorial for making a stream of water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbHqIDLa39I) and modified the water emitter to be 0.1x0.1 meters so that it makes a stringy / gooey like effect.